# How to add time and date columns in power query

Tags: excel, types, powerbi, powerquery

In the power query, I cannot use the + operator to add type date to type time natively. What are some ways to add date and time to create a datetime value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Definitely not intuitive for an Excel user, but the Power Query method is:

`date & time`

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRecords(
        {[date=#date(2022,1,1), time = #time(1,15,0)]},
        type table [date=date, time=time]),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "datetime", each [date] & [time], type datetime)
    
in

    #"Added Custom"
```

[image]

In the MS documentation for Power Query operators it shows `x & y`, where `x=date` and `y=time`, <kbd>=></kbd>`merged datetime`

Answer (score 0):

There are some code snippets that work. You can create a custom function as well if you use these often.

```
DateTime.FromText(Text.Combine({Text.From(DateValue), " ", Text.From(TimeValue)}))
```

Another is to convert them to durations and process them that way.

```
(DateValue - #date(1900,1,1))+(TimeValue - #time(0,0,0)) + #datetime(1900,1,1,0,0,0)
```

OR

```
List.Sum({DateValue - #date(1900,1,1), TimeValue - #time(0,0,0),#datetime(1900,1,1,0,0,0)})
```

Finally

```
#datetime(Date.Year(DateValue), Date.Month(DateValue), Date.Day(DateValue), Time.Hour(TimeValue), Time.Minute(TimeValue), Time.Second(TimeValue))
```

Answer (score 0):

In Power Query Editor just select two columns and left click to Merge Columns
[Power Query Editor - merge columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2t57.png)